# android TextView Layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I want to align the TextViews one on the right the other on the left and each row contain one text view ...
I don't wanna use `Width:fill_parent` `setGravity(Gravity.Right)` coz I am using a background.
here's my code:

```
LinearLayout mainChatLayout = new LinearLayout(main.this);
//ChatText.setId((int)System.currentTimeMillis());
lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
((android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lp).addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, recent.getId());
tv = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//ChatText.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);#800080
if(recent.getId() % 2 == 0) {
    ChatText = new TextView(main.this);
    mainChatLayout.setId((int)System.currentTimeMillis());
    ChatText.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.talk1));
    ChatText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // not working 
    ChatText.setText("some text");
    ChatText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
    ChatText.setPadding(0, 10, 20, 10);
}
else{
    ChatText = new TextView(main.this);
    mainChatLayout.setId((int)System.currentTimeMillis());
    ChatText.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.talk1));
    ChatText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    ChatText.setText("Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    ChatText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
    ChatText.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 10);
}
mainChatLayout.addView(ChatText, tv);
MainLayout.addView(mainChatLayout, lp);
recent = mainChatLayout;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            LinearLayout ll= /// Find Your Layout Using ID
            TextView text=new TextView(this);
```

Now set Structure using LayoutParam. LayoutParam will be type of Parent of TextView

```
    text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100));
    ll.addView(text);
```